# How to append data to existing data object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Im currently using redux to manage my state. The scenario is as such , Upon successful creation of a new object , i would like to append the response data into my existing state container as i don't wish to make a new API call to render it.

## initial State:

```
const initialState = {
workflowobject:{},
```

};

## SAGA:

```
export function* workerCreateTransitionApproval(action) {
const data = yield call(() => axiosInstance.post(`/transition-approval-meta/create/`, action.data))
yield put({ type: "STORE_WORKFLOW_DATA", payload: data.data.data, fetch: 'workflowobject' , label: 'transition_approvals'})
```

}

So over here , i upon recieving the "signal" so to speak to create a transition approval , i will catch that event and create make an axios post request to my backend , which will then return a response of the `transition_approval` . I will then store this `transition_approval` as the payload which i will use later on.

## Reducer

```
const loadWorkflowObject = (state, action) => {
    return updateObject(state, {
        workflowobject: { ...state.workflowobject, [action.label]: action.payload }
    })
}

const storeData = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.fetch) {
        case 'workflowobject': return loadWorkflowObject(state, action)
    }
}

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'STORE_WORKFLOW_DATA': return storeData(state, action);
        case 'CLEAR_CLASS_STATES': return clearClassStates(state, action);
        case 'CLEAR_OBJECT_STATES': return clearObjectStates(state, action);
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default reducer;
```

So in my reducer , it will first go into the case `STORE_WORKFLOW_DATA` which will then return the reducer function `loadWorkflowObject` . This is where i wish to 'append' the data back to the state tree.

## The problem

The tricky part here is that im using this `loadWorkflowObject` reducer for fetching data too , and im already using the spread operator here.

The code that i have shown above will override my preexisting data that i have in the `transition_approvals` object , if possible ,  i would like to append the data in instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this:

```
const loadWorkflowObject = (state, action) => {
    return updateObject(state, {
        workflowobject: { ...state.workflowobject, [action.label]: state. transition_approvals.concat(action.payload) }
    })
}
```

Comment: Hello , thanks for answering , would it be possible to make it 'dynamic' because i would like to share this 'updating' function with the rest of my other types of data

Comment: i've tried replacing transition_approvals with action.label with no success

Comment: have you tried `state[action.label].concat(action.payload)` like that. that should work

Comment: OKAY! i got it , the methodology is spot on , i was just careless to leave out the state.workflowclass (to access the workflowclass state)